# substitute forward slash in formula

Tags: formula

I have a formula where i need to substitute back slash "\" with double back slash "\\".below is the formula

```
HYPERLINK("file:///"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Project_Files_Path__c," 
 ","%20"),"\","\\"),Project_Files_Path__c)
```

[image]

when i check the syntax i am getting above error

Comment: Forward slash- **/** Backslash-\ Your question is confusing. Please edit it. And also replace three slashes (///) with two slashes. That should work.
please explain your scenario, what you want to achieve so that the community can help in a better way.

Comment: I've edited your question to use "back slash" (which is what you're describing) instead of "forward slash". Slashes seem to be like USB (it takes 3 tries to get it right). Also, is that the full text of your error? If not, please [edit] your question to include the full error (no need for an image, just copy/paste the text. If you're feeling fancy, you could also put the error message into a blockquote by putting `>` at the start of the line of text).

Comment: Beyond that, I'd suggest re-evaluating what you're trying to do. Having a link on the internet that points to a file on your own computer usually means that (at best) the link will _only work for you_. If you're trying to make a file available for others, you'll need to actually upload the file and store it in something like an `Attachment` or in a Content Library as a `ContentVersion`.

Answer (score 1):

Checked this one myself, and indeed, the only error salesforce gives us is

> Error: Syntax error

As far as error messages go, that's pretty useless.

The issue, however is that the back slash character `\` is used to escape other characters when Salesforce compiles your formula.

To resolve the error, you need to double the backslashes

This will result in a syntax error:

```
SUBSTITUTE(Name, "\", "\\")
```

While the below formula will compile

```
SUBSTITUTE(Name, "\\", "\\\\")
```

Although this will work as intended (replacing single backslash with double backslash), as I mentioned in the comments, linking to a file on your own computer isn't likely to be what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Provide context on what are you trying to achieve. Irrespective of that, below should help you replace single backslash with two.

```
SUBSTITUTE(Project_Files_Path__c,"\\","\\\\")
```

Comment: This is what OP (**O**riginal **P**oster of the question) already has, and leads to the very generic error they're getting. For things like these which are simple enough to check, I like to try things myself to make sure that my proposed solution will compile without error.

Comment: My bad with formatting. I had posted it as - SUBSTITUTE(Project_Files_Path__c,"\\","\\\\"). Even now when i edit, It shows the one i pasted now. Will take care of this moving forward. Edited it to show correct one. Thanks @DerekF